# Using jq to get json values

Tags: json, jq

Input json:

```json
{
"food_group": "fruit",
"glycemic_index": "low",
    "fruits": {
        "fruit_name": "apple",
        "size": "large",
        "color": "red"
    }
}
```

Below two jq commands work:

```
# jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $key | "\($key), \(.[$key])"' food.json
food_group, fruit
glycemic_index, low
fruits, {"fruit_name":"apple","size":"large","color":"red"}

# jq -r 'keys_unsorted[0:2] as $key | "\($key)"' food.json
["food_group","glycemic_index"]
```

How to get values for the first two keys using jq in the same manner? I tried below

```
# jq -r 'keys_unsorted[0:2] as $key | "\($key), \(.[$key])"' food.json
jq: error (at food.json:9): Cannot index object with array
```

Expected output:

```
food_group, fruit
glycemic_index, low
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a hash array , you can use `to_entries` and that will transform to a array .

After you can use `select` to filter rows you want to keep .

```
 jq -r 'to_entries[]| select(  ( .value | type ) == "string" ) | "\(.key), \(.value)" '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_entries`

```
to_entries[] | select(.key=="food_group" or .key=="glycemic_index") | "\(.key), \(.value)"
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/Aqvos4w7bo